# mod_xsendfile with file url

Tags: php

The apache mod_xsendfile is good for download script
but I want to download a file with a URL like

```
 header("X-Sendfile: http://site.com/a.zip");
```

but it does not work. It shows error 404.

Can you help me about that code?

Answer (score 1):

mod_xsendfile doesn't work like that. You can only send files on the local filesystem.

Comment: can you give me a similar modules that support file URLs

Comment: i want to download a file from a URL but not file from local. can you give me a script?

Comment: If you want to offer a file on an other server you have to use the proxy module.

Answer (score 0):

I got a use case where I'd like to be able to do just this. Instead of having mod_xsendfile read directly from disk, I'd like a similar feature which instead fetches the file from another Apache instance. The file server RAM will be used to buffer files (to minimize disk reads of multiple files) and will not impact on the application server.
Maybe another setup could have been to have JBoss on its own machine and the first level Apache in direct access to the files to be transferred. But that is not how the setup is done today.

```
Internet
|
Apache as a web server
|
|-- JBoss for logic (deciding access to files on the 
|                    file server and adding extra response headers)
|
Apache as a file server, only accessible from the "Apache as a web server"
|
Filesystem
```